# Unable to get browserify-middleware in Express app with Jade template to work

Tags: node.js, express, browserify

I'm coming from the RequireJS world and would like to start using browserify.  I'm building my app with ExpressJS and Node.  I'm at the point where I need to call javascript from within a Jade template view file.  For the sake of testing, I'd like to just use a a simple logging module called `[loglevel]`[1](https://github.com/pimterry/loglevel) that I can call from within the jade template view file.  I installed loglevel via npm and the module source is now in my app's `node_modules` folder.

Inside of app.js that comes standard with a new Express app (abridged):

```
var express      = require('express');
var path         = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var http         = require('http');
var browserify   = require('browserify-middleware');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/javascripts/bundle.js', browserify(['loglevel']));
```

Then in my Jade template I have this (abridged):

```
doctype html
//if IE 8
  html.no-js.lt-ie9(lang='en')  
// [if gt IE 8] <!
|  
html.no-js(lang='en')
  // <![endif]
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0')
    title App Title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/app.css')
    script(src="javascripts/bundle.js")
    script.
      log.info('just a test')
  body#landing
```

When I load the route that brings up this Jade view, my console states: `log is not defined` even though the `loglevel` module should be defining it.  When I check the sources tab in my console, I do see that the browser does, in fact, load `loglevel`.  Since the script is loading, shouldn't I have access to the `log` object that is defined by the `loglevel` module?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see at the [loglevel distribution package](https://github.com/pimterry/loglevel/blob/a93aa4f/dist/loglevel.js#L4-L10), it does either export to CommonJS or to AMD or as a global.

So you should be `require()`ing it first:

```
script.
  require("loglevel").info("just a test");
```